# Swift + Objective C Venmo Pod: 'VENUser.h' file not found

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, venmo

I'm trying to integrate this in a Swift application. I'm using Xcode 6.4 and CocoaPods 0.38.2.

My podfile looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'my_app_name' do
    pod 'Venmo-iOS-SDK', '~>1.3'
end
```

With no import in my bridge header, the app runs. With `#import <Venmo_iOS_SDK/Venmo.h>` however, I get the following error:

```
..Pods/Venmo-iOS-SDK/venmo-sdk/Categories/VENUser+VenmoSDK.h:1:9: 'VENUser.h' file not found
.../my_app_name-Bridging-Header.h:6:9: Could not build module 'Venmo_iOS_SDK' 
Failed to import bridging header '../my_app_name/my_app_name-Bridging-Header.h'
```

The lines at the top of the Venmo.h file are as follows

```
@import Foundation;
@import UIKit;

#import <VENCore/VENCore.h>

#import "VENErrors.h"
#import "VENPermissionConstants.h"
#import "VENSession.h"
#import "VENTransaction+VenmoSDK.h"
```

I tried adding another pod just to make sure it was an issue specifically with my integration with venmo-ios-sdk and ended up adding `#import <VENCore/VENcore.h>` with zero problems. I'm pretty new to iOS, so I don't really know if I'm missing something extra obvious...

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be importing the framework within your bridge header, but instead importing it directly in your Swift code using Swift imports:

```
import Venmo_iOS_SDK
```

Alternatively if you are using the Pod from Objective-C, you should be importing the framework header:

```
#import <Venmo_iOS_SDK/Venmo_iOS_SDK.h>
```

Or, using module imports in Objective-C (http://tonyarnold.com/2014/04/10/clean-up-your-projects-with-xcode-5.html):

```
@import Venmo_iOS_SDK;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there was another way to solve this, but I just edited the pod so in VEnUser+VenmoSDK.h the first line was changed to

```
#import "VENCore/VENUser.h"
```

instead of

```
#import "VENUser.h"
```

I was looking at the wrong file so didn't see the "obvious" error, nor was it particularly obvious to me...but this fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check **Header search paths** or **Library search paths**.
Also can `pod install`.